# Need to find ImageButton in DataGrid Header

Tags: c#, datagrid, updatepanel, imagebutton

So, I have looked everywhere for a solution to this problem I have and everything I have tried so far has failed.

Here's the thing, I need to somehow access multiple button images that have been placed in the headers of a `DataGrid`. I need to access these buttons during an `UpdatePanel_Render` event to change their attributes. However, the `DataGrid` loads **AFTER** the `UpdatePanel` and so I cannot find these controls. I need some help. I've tried everything that I know (which isn't a whole lot). :'(

If you need sample code of some sort or anything, let me know and I will edit this post and provide it.

**Important**

I'm adding on to my question. I decided to place the headers and buttons in a separate `Table` and I managed to add *JavaScript* that re-sizes the `Table` to fit the `DataGrid`. This table is outside of the `UpdatePanel` and the only issue is that when a button is pressed, the `Table` disappears. Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to access these buttons during an UpdatePanel_Render event to change their attributes.

Comment: They are sorting buttons. For some reason, I couldn't get the `DataGrid`'s AllowSort function to work so I just did it myself. So when they are clicked, they need to update the `DataGrid`'s data and how it is displayed, hence why the UpdatePanel is called but it needs to access these buttons because it's going to change their CssClass to show what is active.

Comment: Do you have tried to use jQuery to find those image buttons and do what you need?
[link](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: I did try jQuery but what was happening was the `UpdatePanel` was ignoring my `JavaScript`. I managed to find a solution though and I posted it above. :D

Comment: Instead of adding "Solved" to your title, you are allowed to post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Oh, I guess I could do that. Yeah.. But I figured if people do a search, they'll see the Solved and hopefully click it first? I don't know. :P It's my odd way of thinking.

Comment: Stack Overflow has its own way of indicating solved questions - it's through accepted answers (with a green checkmark). You should move your solution into a new answer below, then mark it accepted once time permits, and remove the "Solved" text from your question as it's unnecessary. You should also do the same for your previous questions.

Comment: Ah okay, I'll do that. Thank you~ ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up figuring out how to get everything to work properly. Here is the snippet of `Javascript` that I used to get the separate `Table` to line up with the `DataGrid` without me having to attempt to access the buttons. :) I haven't actually tried the button stuff yet so... We'll see how it works. Hopefully the `UpdatePanel` isn't too terribly unkind to my work.

*Code*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         //Alters the width of the table upon load
         var defaultRow = $("#<%=ContactHistory.ClientID %> > tbody > tr:first");
         var headerRow = $("#header");
         headerRow.insertBefore(defaultRow);

         //Alters the width of the table after the UpdatePanel finishes
         Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);
            function endRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                var defaultRow = $("#<%=ContactHistory.ClientID %> > tbody > tr:first");
                var headerRow = $("#header");
                headerRow.insertBefore(defaultRow);
            };   
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

do they have ids?

I think you should be able to do this for the grid's itemcreated event.

check to see if the type is grid header, then use findcontrol with the id to locate the buttons.

Comment: I think I know that the issue is and I feel kind of stupid for finding this out now. The `UpdatePanel` is on the outside of the `DataGrid` and so it loads before the `DataGrid`. Therefore, the buttons will never load before the event that calls them. So I need to move the buttons out of the `DataGrid` into it's own `Table` and adjust that `Table` to size over the `DataGrid`.

That's probably what I'll have to do. :/ Annoying but not hard.